# Pentaho - JSON Input not looping over files

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

So I've got about 10 JSON files that I have to stuff into an Elasticsearch setup.  I have 3 steps currently, "Get file names", "JSON Input", and "Elasticsearch bulk insert".  When I look at the Step metrics, I see that Get File Names is correctly reading the 10 files.  But when it comes to the JSON input, only the first file is processed.  What could be going on.

Here is an image of my setup, and I've attached the ktr file.

[image]

[Link to the ktr file as it stands currently](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L42ioGrLEDQ79rsAFSoFzsvMq0KFNX4V)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the Content tab of the step you have the "Limit" atribute set to 1, you can Edit this by unchecking the "Source is from a previous step" option in the File tab, then you set "Limit" to 0.